# NPM Provider not visible in Sonatype Nexus 2.13.0 OSS

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I am trying to setup a NPM Proxy Repository using Nexus 2.13.0 OSS.

According to the documentation there should be a NPM Provider available during proxy repository creation. Unfortunately I can only select "Maven1", "Maven2" and "NuGet". I don't get what I am doing wrong. Nexus is installed on a RedHat Linux machine, NPM and Node are installed, too. Can anybody help, please? I know that I can use Nexus 3 for NPM support, but we need YUM support, so we have to stay with Nexus 2.

Thanks in advance,
Mirko

Comment: Are you using the war version?  Npm is only available in the jetty bundle.  Also I'd recommend upgrading to 2.14.4 for npm, that version has support for scoped packages.